# update a spring cache when a table update happens through sql procedure

Tags: java, spring, caching, stored-procedures, ehcache

I have a spring boot application with java 8 ,`jpa` etc and a `jboss` application with j2ee applications which calls too many sql procedures to update the table.

I have a query something like this in spring boot to get all the employee:

```
@Cacheable("employeeList")

List{Employee} findByAddressId(Long addressId);
```

But if someone inserts a new record to Employee table in the same address id  from sql procdure from jboss application, the spring boot application is not able to pick the new records , because the query is so generic to that address id.

So i want to create a trigger on that table on insert and update , so when ever insert/update happens it should update the cache with new records belongs to that address id.

Can somebody please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you have a spring boot app and a separate jboss app that are connecting to the same database and are insert/updating to the same database tables.

With spring's @Cachable you need to be able to tell spring when you should evict the cached item. For example, having the method that updates the entity being marked as @CacheEvict is an easy way to evict the entity from the cache. The problem here is that if the jboss app updates a record there is no way for spring boot app to know this.

Using a database trigger would seem problematic since you'd have to somehow have the db trigger communicate to the spring boot app to allow eviction to happen.

One solution may be having both the jboss and spring boot app use a distributed caches, like ehcache with terracotta.

Comment: Thanks John for replying, I thought of using ehcache, but it will not be real time data, as they have to wait till the time we have set up in ehcache timetolive ,correct me if i am wrong, And with terracotta could you please elaborate,i have no idea on that?? How about using a using a Trigger to update a say "event table" to know which cache to refresh, with some mechanism to refresh a particular cache only.